# When to use map, and when to use apply?

Tags: r, purrr

The following do the same thing. When would one use map, and when would one use apply?

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
mtcars %>% map(function(x) sum(x)^2)
```

or:

```
mtcars %>% apply(2,function(x) sum(x)^2)
```

Comment: where did you get `map` from? `purrr`?

Comment: @Sotos purrr::map

Comment: @David Arenburg, Consequences?

Comment: `map` creates a list and `apply` doesn't...?!?

Comment: `apply` first convert your `data.frame` into a `matrix` and this can have some unwanted consequences...

Comment: And when would one use `colSums(mtcars)^2`? Or `data.table::as.data.table(mtcars)[,lapply(.SD,sum)]^2`?

Comment: You can read about the *purrr* philosophy in the [readme](https://github.com/hadley/purrr/blob/master/README.md) and about *purrr* and type-stability [here](https://blog.rstudio.org/2016/01/06/purrr-0-2-0/).  As you can tell by the comments so far, a lot of this is personal preference.